# How to use ArrayList to call a method from another class in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a total beginner at Java and we have a program to do on Bingo. You have to let the user enter the number of players and each player receives a board. Then a random token is called from another class and you have to use that token to mark it on the board. I don't know how to figure out who won...and there's an error on Mark(). Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Bingo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
     Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter number of players: ");
     int num = a.nextInt();
     ArrayList<Board> player = new ArrayList<Board>();
     for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
       player.add(new Board());
     Token one = new Token();
     int tempNumber = 0, tempLetter = 0;
     boolean win = false;
     while(win = false)
     {
       tempLetter = one.getLetter();
       tempNumber = one.getNumber();

       char letter;
       if(tempLetter == 0)
       letter = 'B';
       else if(tempLetter == 1)
         letter = 'I';
       else if(tempLetter == 2)
         letter = 'N';
       else if(tempLetter == 3)
         letter = 'G';
       else
         letter = 'O';

       System.out.println("Token: " + tempNumber + letter);
       System.out.println();

       win = player.Mark(tempNumber,tempLetter);
     }
  }
}
```

Here is the Board class:

```
public class Board
{
    private int[][] card;
    private int row, column;
    boolean bingo;
    public Board()
    {
        card = new int[5][5];
        for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
                card[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 75 + 1);
        card[2][2] = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(card[i][j] + " ");
                if(j == 4)
                    System.out.println();
            }
    bingo = false; //False
    row = 0;
    column = 0;

}

public boolean Mark(int x, int y)
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(card[i][j] == x)
                if(j == y)
                {
                    card[i][j] = 0;
                    row = i;
                    column = j;
                }

        }
    System.out.println("Mark: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(card[i][j] + " ");
            if(j == 4)
                System.out.println();
        }
    Check();
    return bingo;
}

private void Check()
{
    int flagRow = 0, flagColumn = 0, flagDiagonal = 0;
    int tempRow = 0, tempColumn = 0, tempRow1 = 4, tempColumn1 = 4;
    //Diagonal check
    if(row == column)
    {
        while(bingo == false)
        {
            if(card[tempRow][tempColumn] == 0)
            {
                tempRow++;
                tempColumn++;
                flagDiagonal++;
            }
            else if(card[tempRow1][tempColumn1] == 0)
            {
                tempRow1--;
                tempColumn1--;
                flagDiagonal++;
            }

            if(flagDiagonal == 5)
                bingo = true;
            else
            {
                tempRow = 0;
                tempColumn = 0;
                tempRow1 = 4;
                tempColumn1 = 4;
                flagDiagonal = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Row and column check
    for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(card[i][column] == 0) //Column check
                flagColumn++;
            if(card[row][j] == 0) //Row check
                flagRow++;
        }

    if(flagRow == 5)
        bingo = true;
    else if(flagColumn == 5)
        bingo = true;
    else
    {
        flagRow = 0;
        flagColumn = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("\nCheck: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < card.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < card[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(card[i][j] + " ");
            if(j == 4)
                System.out.println();
        }
    System.out.println("Bingo status: " + bingo);
   }
}
```

And here is the Token class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Token
{
    ArrayList<Integer> number;
    public Token()
    {
        number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 75; i++)
            number.add((int)(Math.random() * 75 + 1));
    }
    public int getNumber()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int temp = number.get(rand.nextInt(number.size()));

        number.remove(temp);
        return temp;
    }

    public int getLetter()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int temp = number.get(rand.nextInt(number.size()));
        if(temp >= 1 && temp <= 15)
            return 0; //B
        else if(temp >= 16 && temp <= 30)
            return 1; //I
        else if(temp >= 31 && temp <= 45)
            return 2; //N
        else if(temp >=46 && temp <= 60)
            return 3; //G
        return 4; //O
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone! I know...this is a long program.

Comment: "I know...this is a long program." - Actually, it's not. But too much for this Site's format. Please read [ask] and reduce your snippets to the relevant parts. [mcve]

Comment: to solve the error use something like `player.get().Mark();`

Comment: *"there's an error on `Mark()`"*, what's the error? Could you specify?

Comment: *"I don't know how to figure out who won.."* AFAIR to win you need to be the first who have (some) of the numbers drawn in a line on your board. So you need a 2 dimensional representation of a board for each player where you can put random numbers on (but no number twice) and a list of numbers drawn so fahr. After each draw you need to check for each player if any line on her board has each number occuring in the list of drawn numbers...

Comment: It states: the method Mark(int, int) is undefined for Arraylist<Board>

Comment: " while(win = false) " You would wanna replace this line with  'while(win == false) '. The operator '=' is used to assign a value to a variable in java, whereas comparison for equality is done via '==' operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `player.Mark(tempNumber,tempLetter);` where `player` is an `ArrayList<Board>` which doesn't have that method. It is defined in the class `Board` itself.

So you want to `get` the current `Board` instance from this list and call `Mark` on **that**.

i.e. `win = player.get(currentPlayerIndex).Mark(tempNumber,tempLetter);`

Depending on your logic you need some `currentPlayerIndex` that gets the current Player/Board.

**Note:** as @opensam mentioned, you need to replace `while(win = false)` with `while(win == false)` or else you'll assign `false` to `win` and the loop breaks before you can do one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

> and there's an error on Mark().

'player' is an instance of ArrayList class whereas Mark(int,int) is a method defined for your class Board. If you want to call method Mark(int,int), you will have to call it via an instance of class Board. If you dont understand what that means then please go through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm).